# CAN nodes having different reference potential

Tags: can

I have four electronic modules with on-board CAN circuitry, so each module serves as a node. Each module is at a different reference potential. How can I connect all these nodes to a common CAN bus?

Comment: Schematic or it didn't happen.

Comment: What is the span of those different reference potentials? 7.3 volt?

Answer (score 1):

Use an optical isolator. You can buy them readily made. Please check if the isolation voltage is big enough for your application.

Comment: Hi Sascha, Thanks for the answer. The difference in the reference potential of nodes is around 28V. Can you explain your answer in terms of power source of optical isolator and integrity of CAN signals at the output of isolator.

Comment: @Anand: I am afraid that my answer contains as many details as your question. Isolating 28V should not be a problem, but in respect to oprtating optical isolators on this bus and the implications on your application, i recommend that you look up some specific datasheets and see how these fit into your plans.

Comment: Yes, isolation. With Si8621 or ISO1050 for example.

Comment: @Sascha: Since CAN is a two way communication, I think using optical isolator will not serve the purpose.

Comment: @anand: did you Google for "optical isolation can bus"? I guess the commercially available isolators actually contain several channels in both direction.